# How to implement an IObservable

Tags: c#, .net-core, observable, system.reactive

I want to be able to use a `Queue` as an `Observable` and i do not know how to create it. I want it to be able to push data whenever someone calls `Enqueue`.

```
class Producer:IObservable<int>
{
    private object @lock = new object();
    private Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>();
    List<IObserver<int>> observers = new List<IObserver<int>>();

    public Producer()
    {
    }
    public IObservable<int> ToObservable()
    {
        return ///
    }
    public bool Enqueue(int sample)
    {
        if (sample == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        this.queue.Enqueue(sample);
        return true;
    }
    public int Dequeue()
    {
        if(!this.queue.TryDequeue(out Sample rez))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return rez;
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<int> observer)
    {
    }
}
```

I can handle the part with the `Subscriber` and `IObserver` i just don't know how to wrap my `Producer` object in an `IObservable`

Comment: Sorry i forgot to change.I was wondering how to wrap the class in an observable?

Comment: Why not just use a `Subject<int>`?

Comment: I am not familiar with that, is it the same ?

Comment: Take a look at http://introtorx.com/ for a introduction to `IObservable<T>` and Reactive Extensions in general. The page is outdated, but the concepts still apply.

Comment: I see it has already been answered. Not sure if the Queue<int> is still useful though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you would not implement `IObservable<T>` by yourself in favor of [Reactive Extensions](https://reactivex.io/). Think of observables as alternatives to classic events like below:

```
class Producer
{
    private Queue<int> _queue = new Queue<int>();
    private Subject<int> _whenEnqueued = new Subject<int>();

    public IObservable<int> WhenEnqueued => _whenEnqueued.AsObservable();        

    public void Enqueue(int value)
    {
        _queue.Enqueue(value);
        _whenEnqueued.OnNext(value);
    }
}
```

This way outher classes can subscribe `WhenEnqueued` and get notified of new values by delegating the work to the `Subject` class.

If your really want to implement `IObservable<T>` (usually you don't) take a look at the example at the [IObservable documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iobservable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Please put an `.AsObservable()` on the line `public IObservable<int> WhenEnqueued => _whenEnqueued;`. Right now you're passing a reference to the subject that any external code can cast to and end your subject.